# Google cloud dataprep - how to create hash of a column

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataprep

can anyone point to a out of the box or custom implementation in Cloud Dataprep to create hash of another column, like bigquery has FARM_FINGERPRINT.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Trifacta, which powers Trifacta does not have built-in hashing. Their recommednation is to use [user-defined functions](https://docs.trifacta.com/display/r050/Java+UDFs?os_username=tr29r050usr%26&os_password=%2A1ads%40flfg%40npa%28%3DPPKz) for this purpose. Cloud Dataprep does not support UDFs.

I'd recommend doing one of the following:

1. Hashing the data before you wrangle it in Dataprep
2. Obscuring the data through other means, such as fuzzy number formatting